# Object Not Initialized in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working in Rails and have the following class:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :name, :rating, :team_name
    def initialize(name, rating, team_name)
        @name = name
        @rating = rating
        @team_name = team_name
    end
end
```

When I run

```
bundle exec rails console
```

and try:

```
a = Player.new("me", 5.0, "UCLA")
```

I get back:

```
 => #<Player not initialized>
```

I have no idea why the Player object wouldn't be initialized here.  Any suggestions on what to do / explanation for what might be causing this?

Thanks,
Mariogs

Comment: Do you have a players table defined in your database? And have you migrated your database to ensure it is up to date? Or did you mean to descend your class from other than ActiveRecord::Base?

Comment: Yeah, I just dropped, created, and migrated to ensure its existence.  Same issue arises when I try to create an instance of Player tho.

Comment: I think you are trying to solve a problem with the wrong approach but it is difficult to advise the best approach when there is no clear understanding of the need to provide the virtual attributes as part of the initialize method, I have answered your original question and tried to provide some pointers as to why you should think of a different solution but it might be better to ask another question on what your attributes are for and what the best approach would be!

Comment: Also you might be interested in this http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes-revised It's a revised cast so you would have to subscribe to watch bit there is no better time to subscribe than right ow because Ryan is on an extended break and you will not be charged another subscription fee until he returns which may not be for a long while yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> have no idea why the Player object wouldn't be initialized here

It's not initilised quite simply because you have not initialised it!

You have overriden the ActiveRecord::Base initialize method but you are not calling through to it it so the Player class is not initialised properly

Just call super

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :name, :rating, :team_name
    def initialize(name, rating, team_name)
        super
        @name = name
        @rating = rating
        @team_name = team_name
    end
end
```

You probably didn't mean to override the initialize method at all, it's strongly discouraged http://blog.dalethatcher.com/2008/03/rails-dont-override-initialize-on.html, you probably meant to make use of the after_initialize callback so you can split the name, rating and team_rating out from the params hash that is passed in to whatever method causes the player model to be intialised in the first place

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  I thought by defining an initialize method I could use it to pass arguments when instantiating a Player, no?

Comment: @Mariogs: yes, but it's an activerecord object and activerecord needs to do initialization too. You need the call to super.

Comment: in related news, even when I add super as in your example, I get this error: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..2).  Why is it saying "0..2" as if it's a range?

Comment: @Mariogs I think you are going to face many other issues as well, see my edited answer

Comment: hmm.  so is there no way for me to use the normal ruby syntax of Object.new(arg1, arg2, ...)?

Comment: @Mariogs Model.new takes a params hash rather than a series of individual params, see my comment on your question, I think you need to explain why you are trying to do this but it's a very different question to the one you asked.